# ApplicationScoped Bean eager=true destroys when switching to different view

Tags: jsf, primefaces

JSF2, Primefaces 3.3.FINAL, Spring

I have ApplicationScoped Bean for loading all dropdown data during start up of server. I referenced the same bean via ManagedProperty annotation. But when switching views the bean gets destroyed and i need to recreate the bean and data again.

Sample Code:

```
   @ManagedBean(name = "refDataBean", eager = true)
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class RefDataBean extends AbsBackingBean implements Serializable{
   ....
     @PostConstruct
     public void init(){
     //load multiple drop down data - populateData-db call
     }
   }


   @ManagedBean(name = "searchViewBean")
   @ViewScoped
   public class SearchViewBean{

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{refDataBean}")
   private RefDataBean        refDataBean;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { //getUser object }

   public User retrieveUser(User user) {
           List<User> userList = refDataBean.getUserList();
   }

   public PICTSRefDataBean getPictsRefDataBean() {
      return pictsRefDataBean;
   }

   public void setPictsRefDataBean(final PICTSRefDataBean pictsRefDataBean)      
   {     this.pictsRefDataBean = pictsRefDataBean;  }

   }
```

In one page/view, user.xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu  value="#{searchViewBean.selectedUser}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{refDataBean.userList}" var="taskUser"
            itemLabel="#{taskUser.fullNameAndId}"
            itemValue="#{taskUser.networkLogin}"></f:selectItems>              
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When switching to another page, team.xhtml, the refDataBean is null and it goes to PostConstruct method of RefDataBean constructing the whole drop down list again. Since its a static data, i expect load it once and should be able to access in any page. I know that Objects in View scope are destroyed when you switch to a different view. How to restrict that? Or what am i missing? Please help

Comment: To avoid the obvious, what package did you import `@ApplicationScoped` from?

Comment: Thats not the package . He means import for example `import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;`

Comment: All beans reside in the same package. we have several ViewScoped Bean and ViewScoped bean refers to ApplicationScoped bean to pull the data.

Comment: The real problem is after visiting another xhtml , the refDataBean is initialized and goes to **@PostConstruct** and reconstruct the bean

Comment: Can you show here, how you're navigating to the other page?

Comment: I found the root cause, the RefDataBean was extending ViewScopedBean, hence the initialization of RefDataBean. Thanks all for the responses